# const time = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21] Как можно по другому создать такой массив. чтоб не писать все цифры

Tags: javascript

```js
const time = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Как можно по другому создать такой массив. чтоб не писать все цифры

Answer (score 3):

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 9; i <= 21; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```

---

```js
let arr = Array.from({length: 13}, (_, i) => i + 9)

console.log(arr);
```

---

```js
let arr = [...Array(13).keys()].map(i => i + 9);

console.log(arr);
```